# Should I accept the answer that I end up using or the one that is helpful?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I asked the question *[How to implement filter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23866442/how-to-implement-efficient-filtering-logic-in-python)* yesterday. Since I am a beginner, and English is not my first language, I had a hard time trying to clearly explain what I wanted to ask. So, I ended up using multiple photos to explain my situation.

Eventually, I received two answers. One answer is from **Martijn Pieters** which explains how to execute a query in the database [SQLAlchemy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLAlchemy).

But because of my poor knowledge of programming, at the first glance, I could not make out how his example works. I have to admit that I didn't fully look into the documentation of SQLAlchemy, but I was desperate to get my job done as quickly as possible, so I ended up querying out all the data in the database into a Python dictionary and used the method provided by **TurpIF** (second answer).

I assume that my method is not good for a big database as it has to query out the whole database into memory before I start doing anything. It would be much wiser to filter out at the database layer rather than in Python code itself.

But now, I am in a dilemma. Should I mark the answer that I ended up using as accepted or the one that seems to be a better way? What should I do if I see the same problem in future Stack Overflow posts?

Comment: Take your time deciding. There's no rush to accept, and you _probably_ already recognise that one is a quick-fix with limitations and the other is "the right way to do it". Even if you're not using it right now, one clearly offers better (subjective) advice. In your position I would upvote both (I expect you already did), and come back to decide in a week - after I'd already burnt myself with the quick-fix and implemented the better solution =).

Comment: I like to separate what was helpful to the questioner and what is helpful to the community, because it doesn't have to be the same. The first is indicated by the check mark, the other by the votes. That way everyone decides for himself.

Comment: May be I will just leave it without accepting any answer for now. I have up voted both and I will come back when I have free time to test both solutions and only then I will accept the answer whcih I think is useful.

Answer (score 87):

Interesting dilemma. This is from the Stack Overflow Help guidelines on answering (the emphasis is mine):

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final
>   statement indicating that the question has now been answered
>   perfectly. It simply means that the **author received an answer that
>   worked for him or her personally,** but not every user comes back to
>   accept an answer, and of those who do, they may not change the
>   accepted answer if a newer, better answer comes along later.

So I would take that to imply you should mark that one that worked for you *personally*. Presumably the voting process will help others find what will work for their use-case.

Comment: Exactly this is why feature requests for "community accepted answer" were declined: the OP accepts based on his personal experience, the community will vote, and the highest vote is the community accepted answer.

Comment: @PlasmaHH While I agree with that statement I think prominence of the selected answer tick, outweigh the number of votes. Especially for users not familiar with the site.

Comment: @Nate: I think only to a certain degree. If the number of upvotes is clearly much higher, it is clear to new users too. Especially in the (too often) case of the accepted having 0 or 1 votes.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I think users are trained from certain other sites, that the green tick by the OPs selected answer, indicate that that is **the** solution to the question, not the one OP found to personally help them the most. In the (what I see anecdotal as) rare case where that answer has a low score and another answer has a higher score I think new users can be confused. Obviously if they are looking for a solution, they will try both and use what works for them.

Comment: @Nate you make a really good point... However, I think this is more a UX problem based on the prominence of the tick rather than an indication that people should not tick the answer they used personally.

Comment: @Nate If a non-accepted answer receives enough upvotes, it will actually be placed vertically above the accepted answer. If the votes are very close, then I would agree with you, but in general, "first answer below the question" trumps any visibility the check mark might give. It's also not StackOverflow's fault if a poor programmer doesn't take the time to read more than one answer; I myself try to make a habit of doing so and then choosing one to implement based on my own needs.

Comment: @jpmc26: Re: "If a non-accepted answer receives enough upvotes, it will actually be placed vertically above the accepted answer": I've never seen that. Can you link to such an answer?

Comment: Also, the "better" (but not accepted) answer has a chance at earning its creator one of the coveted "Populist" gold badges.

Comment: @ruakh: I can tell you it's happened to my answers a couple of times, but both times the OP came back a few days later and switched the checkmark to mine, so now it's not an example of that anymore.

Comment: @Chuck: That happens if the user who asked the question [accepts their own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/). Otherwise, I believe the accepted answer is always on top (assuming no [client-side shenanigans](http://stackapps.com/questions/4570/code-golf-se-answer-sorter)).

Comment: There's a load of reasons why additional good answers might not be 'accepted'. Not least - an answer many years after the question was asked. Keeping on top of 'accepting' seems unreasonable, so from that perspective the only possible answer is 'whichever one helped you (most)'. 

Comprehensive answers are generally good, but concise and accurate may be more directly helpful.

Answer (score 11):

Accepting an answer that is *not* helpful for others is a waste in all regards. Most viewers of a question come through Google looking for a solution. They will now first see an less helpful answer. The asker is just one of the dozens of people benefiting from that question.

Accept the answer that is most useful to the dozens of people coming after you. I acknowledge that the SO guidelines say otherwise but I think they are wrong. They should be changed so that useful behavior is encouraged.

What is the purpose of accepting? Certainly to enrich the site and be more helpful. So chose the most helpful answer for the majority of people.

Comment: If the poster uses Answer 1 to solve their problem, and doesn't use Answer 2, but then thinks answer 2 might be the "better" answer and ticks it as the accepted one (without even using it) then there is an untested accepted answer... Seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: Most answers only show a concept, not production code.

Comment: true, but even with conceptual answers, if the user goes ahead and implements one approach, gets it working but finds it difficult, and thus thinks the other (untested answer) might've been better we end up with an accepted answer that hasn't even been tested.

Comment: -1 The voting process will help visitors decide what is the best solution. The accepted answer is there to show what helped the OP personally.

Comment: And who is interested to see what helped him most? Only he. Visitors will not see the highest-voted answer first.

Comment: @usr Visitors who have similar constraints that the OP had at the time.

Answer (score 9):

I personally go for a much more subjective interpretation. I accept the answer that

1. Provides a valid solution, or at least *leads to* a valid solution, that
2. I think helped me solve, or at least begin to understand, the problem, and that
3. **I like the best.**

Which solution, if any, I *use* is irrelevant. The one that gives me the most insight and/or that I consider the most elegant is the one I choose.

Answer (score 7):

The point of accepting an answer is that it sends a clear signal to anyone else faced with a similar problem. By accepting you confirm that the proposed solution worked for your problem scenario. Now that scenario is not limited to just the problem, for instance "how to implement a filter" but also includes metadata like your technical background, skill level, experience and goals.

In your particular example you specifically mention you want an efficient solution *at development time* (to prevent a forest of if statements) and that you want to find out how to implement this requirement in Python so you can write and refine your own code. What your question then signals is that you're new to the concept, possibly the programming language and want a solution that is functionally sound, intuitive and more practical than the solution you already discovered.

If we take that into consideration the answer by Martijn is not particularly useful to you as it requires a third party toolkit and doesn't show you how to implement this yourself in pure Python. The other answer did show you exactly what you needed with minimal development time. That is the answer you should accept.

Anyone else stumbling on your question later will usually first read the question to see if his scenario matches yours. Many will also be new to the concept of filters and wondering how to implement them and the second answer will again be the one they'll find most useful. At the same time, if it's someone looking for a *runtime efficient* approach he might not even check the answers when he realizes you were mostly concerned with development time, not runtime. But if he checks the answers he'll see an accepted answer that isn't useful to him but also one with a lot of upvotes that suggest a dedicated toolkit which might be just what he needs.

To summarise, the majority of users looking up a question will be in a similar or identical situation to the one who asked it. It therefore makes sense to accept an answer that is the most suited to that particular situation.

Comment: This doesn't just apply to "How do I do X?" questions but also "What is the fastest/safest/easiest way to do X?". Every question will have different priorities when it comes to a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would upvote each, and comment that I did so.  If I *used* the "quick fix" and it worked for me, that makes it eligible for the checkmark.  If I did *not* use the "correct solution", then I actually don't know if it works at all, or if it requires more explanation to implement, or anything about it, really.

So, I'd check the one I got to work.  If I later had cause to go back and implement the "correct solution" for this situation or some other similar situation (or just that my understanding increased to the point that I completely "get" it now), and found it to be better, then I'd probably go back and change the accepted answer accordingly (and update it with any additional details needed to implement it, and probably note that I changed my choice and why I found it to be better).

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you mentioned in your question

> Assuming that I have already query out the data for all the fruits and store them in dictionary like this:

So whilst the answer that suggested using `sqlalchemy` is an excellent answer, the one that worked based on your stated assumption is actually the best one *for you*, and therefore if I were you I wouldn't lose any sleep over accepting the second answer!

You can always upvote the first, and leave a comment explaining that the second fits your question better

Answer (score 2):

If you ended up using an answer that means it was helpful.

Accept that answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to accepting the best answer (for me) I would add comments to both answers explaining the usefulness of each. That might explain you accepting that particular answer to other readers.

Let the community votes do the rest.

Accepting an answer just because you used it at first is useless to you and the community.

On a side note: accepting an answer does not stop the community from adding more/alternative answers. The community will vote (or not).

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced scenarios where

- A popular answer helped my case instead of an accepted answer
- There are even scenarios where an isolated answer at the bottom with lesser votes than the popular or better answer but catered to my situation helped me because of the environment like Mac vs Windows or because or a particular version of the software
- Thus I would essentially consider **the answer that helped me** as the right answer even though  there is a better answer. Now unless I tried the better solution and find that would be more efficient one, then feel free to unselect your answer and mark the one you find much helpful as the better one. Just ask yourself this

> If I am in the exact same problem in the future and end up at this exact question again in the future, which would be the best solution for me

This will help you decide cause you may not want to go through the same trial and error again and just using the efficient way may be the best way ahead.