# Rewarding a bounty - most helpful or simple fix

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169203/cloning-a-relation-in-rails/29756596) a while ago, which got little attention, so I added a bounty. I then got a few good answers. There was one answer, by Alejandro Babio, which seemed to be very helpful. An almost guide on how to find the problem and this would have worked if I followed his advise (simple debugging exercise with Gems).

I then received another answer from marcus3006 which actually perfectly addressed the issue. The answer itself was a reasonable quick fix and solved by problem with very little effort. However it was a nuance of my scenario, that it's unlikely to help a lot of other people (the fact that I was using a particular Gem in my code that wasn't mentioned in the original question as I didn't think it relevant).

My question is, who do I award the bounty to? The answer which perfectly solves **my** problem  (I've upvoted this and am probably going to accept it). Or the answer that is most useful to other users (I've upvoted this)?

Comment: I don't think that there's much to say here.. the answer given by Alejandro is well researched, explained in detail, and thousands of times more useful to future users than a specific solution like the one provided by Marcus.

Comment: I agree - But Marcus's is what I'll be using. As per http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256311/671422 I should accept the answer that worked for me. It just seems a bit strange to accept one answer but give the bounty to another?

Comment: It's perfectly fine to award the bounty and accept mark to two different answers.

Comment: Really, it's your bounty and you decide what to do with it.