# Two very good, yet different answers - which one should I accept?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, self-answer

I had a problem and tried to solve it with certain technique (let's call it "technique A"), but failed.

I've asked a question similar to: "What am I doing wrong with this technique A?" and described my problem as an example.

I've received two answers. First one showed how to properly use "technique A". Second one pointed out that **I shouldn't be using "technique A"** in the first place, as it won't solve my problem.

In other words: first answer answered my question, second answer pointed out that finding out an answer to my question won't solve my problem.

What should I do now?

- Accept first answer, as it's actually a direct (and proper) answer to question asked. However, it didn't help to solve my problem.
- Accept second answer, as it actually solved my problem. Yet, it does not answer a question.
- Answer a question by myself, combining (and referencing) both answers (and, possibly some other valuable comments) and accepting it.

This meta question is different than:

- [This one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262210/whats-the-right-way-to-self-answer-if-other-answers-assisted) as in my case both answers were fully right and I don't have to apply any changes.
- [This one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256301/should-i-accept-the-answer-that-i-end-up-using-or-the-one-that-is-helpful) as both answers mentioned there answered question directly (where in my case one answer is direct and second points out a flaw in my question).

Comment: Do you have a coin you can flip?

Comment: @MartinJames: unfortunatelly, only banknotes, gold bars and diamond necklaces =/

Comment: personally i would vote up both answers and combine them on an answer of my own and accepting that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't select an answer that did not solve your problem, that doesn't help anybody.  That somebody could interpret your question correctly and find the real issue is certainly not unusual.  It is the common outcome for [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

You can fix your question to match the answer but it is not unlikely that it is better that you don't.  Another programmer that's going to google your question some day may well have fell into the same trap and assume that A was going to work.  We don't really like XY problems but there are some that are so common that they need to be covered.  You were not specific enough to make the call, it is up to you.