# What can be done about users who do not seem to understand when answers should be accepted (or not)?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Over the past couple of days, I've been running into a series of questions posted by [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7403752/edyvedy13). They are all related to trying to run a standalone executable they found online - both on its own and through Python - and the questions I'm referring to can be found here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/44398650/3775798
- [How can I convert stl files to ply files efficiently in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44437303/3775798)
- [When I run executable from python and pass the arguements I get nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44461610/3775798)

I thought I saw an opportunity to help someone out, so on the first question at least I put in some time commenting on it and posted an answer, which the user then accepted.

Later, they posted the other two questions, including the third one posted today. They indicated in that question that they were able to run the executable on its own successfully ([most recent revision showing this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44461610/3)), but then they came back to the first question and un-accepted my answer since they could not run the executable from Python and get the same output from it ([as indicated in a comment on my answer for their first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398650/i-cannot-open-and-run-the-exe-file/44398761?noredirect=1#comment75919459_44398761)).

In short, I'm seeing this as them accepting my answer for their first question, then coming back and unaccepting it because they could not get it to work under different conditions listed in their third question. I am confused by this, and admittedly a little offended.

Then, I saw on the third question today that [someone else posted an answer on it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44461748/3775798). The OP then [stated that it did not work for them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461610/when-i-run-executable-from-python-and-pass-the-arguements-i-get-nothing#comment75920159_44461748), but accepted it anyway.

To sum up, there's two parts to this:

1. The OP accepted Answer 1 to Question 1. They showed it worked for them as far as Question 1 is concerned in the question text for Question 3.
2. The OP did not find that Answer 1 resolved Question 3 (which is understandable, because it was a separate question), then came back and unaccepted Answer 1 because it did not answer Question 3, even though it was never posted there. Additionally, they accepted Answer 3 on Question 3, even though they explicitly stated that it did not resolve their issue.

This then leads me to wonder if they really know what it means to accept answers on different questions on this site, because at this point I don't really get why they keep clicking that checkmark.

Other than pointing the user in question to [this help center page on accepting answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), is there anything else that can really be done here?

Comment: As the help center page says, accepting an answer is for the answer most helpful to you as the question author.  If they think your answer isn't helpful, or another answer on another question *is* helpful, that's their feedback to provide, even if you disagree.

Comment: @Servy I understand that. But what I don't get is when they ask two separate questions for separate things, accept an Answer 1 on Question 1 when Answer 1 solves it (and they acknowledge it), then unaccept Answer 1 because it doesn't solve the separate problem asked in Question 2.

Comment: Because they found the answer that *you* don't like as much helpful, and the answer that *you* think is a good solution to not be helpful.

Comment: FYI, I left a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461610/when-i-run-executable-from-python-and-pass-the-arguements-i-get-nothing#comment75924719_44461610) to that user so maybe they will tell their version of the story (I think it's fair letting them know they are being discussed here)

Comment: @Servy Sorry, but not really following your reasoning here as it applies to this case. The user unaccepted an answer that solved their first question, then unaccepted it because it didn't answer another *separate* question they had. The same user also accepts an answer on the other question, *even though they explicitly stated it did not solve their problem*. I'm talking about the apparent disconnect between these things and what they're accepting, which AFAICT may as well be random.

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton You're saying that there's a disconnect between the answers that *you* think solve the problem, and the answers that the *question author* thinks are helpful.  They don't need to be the same thing; they may well be different.  Just because *you* feel that a given answer answers the question doesn't mean that the OP has to think that it's helpful, and just because you think an answer doesn't answer the question doesn't mean the OP can't think it was helpful.

Comment: *"What can be done about users who do not seem to understand when answers should be accepted (or not)?"*...stop answering their questions. That's about all you can do.

Comment: @Servy Please, look carefully at the links I've provided. Answer 1 is **provably** helpful, because they used my advice - and it *worked*! - in the other question. They even accepted it (at first). That the OP does not find my answer helpful because he found it helpful as indicated elsewhere is absurd. I'm really not sure how much more clearly I can get this point across.

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton Saying that you personally think that the answer was helpful doesn't mean that everyone else is obligated to agree.  Whether someone feels an answer is helpful to them is *their own opinion*.  You can't tell someone else what they think is helpful, only they can.  I'm really not sure how much more clearly I can get this point across.

Comment: Accepting an answer is **entirely up to the OP**. We can't make them do **anything** here.

Comment: @Servy I think the point Christopher's making is that yep, it's up to the OP to decide what's helpful to them or not, but given the chain of events maybe the OP didn't understand that the idea is to choose the answer that's most helpful to them, and is there anything that could/should be done other than pointing them to the docs to help that fact get across.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not saying the user should be forced to accept an answer. That's not what I'm saying here. I guess an analogy is if they ask for a tool to turn a screw with, so I give them a screwdriver and they pay me for it; they then show me they can turn a screw with it. But then they find on their own that the screwdriver can't hammer nails, so they bring the screwdriver back for a refund. At any rate, I will not be helping this particular user again if he's going to use the answers I am providing him, then make me feel like I wasted my time for it.

Comment: @Clive And the point *I'm* making is that just because *they* think an answer is or isn't helpful doesn't mean that the OP agrees; just because *they* indicate that an answer was or wasn't helpful to them doesn't mean that they don't understand what acceptance is there for.

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton So in your situation you would demand that the person claim that what they were provided with was helpful to them, when it wasn't actually helpful to them?  Again, the acceptance feature is for the author to indicate what answer they felt was most helpful to them; if the answer wasn't helpful to them *they shouldn't be indicating that it was helpful to them*.

Comment: @Servy Of course, but it also doesn't mean they _do_ understand what acceptance is there for, and perhaps making it more immediately obvious somehow would help the question askers who fall into the "don't understand" category along a bit. I'm not saying that's what I think, but I think that's what this meta post is about rather than trying to find a way to force an opinion on anyone

Comment: @Servy The screwdriver was helpful for turning screws. That's what they asked for. If they wanted something that could also hammer nails, then they should have said that in the first place instead of saying they were happy with the screwdriver. I thought that's why we ask users to be clear in their questions and make each separate concern its own separate, self-contained post? But at any rate, I feel like I'm talking to a broken record, so I'm just going to stop talking here.

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton Yes, a screwdriver *would* have been helpful for turning screws, but the person didn't need to turn screws, so *it wasn't helpful for them*.  Not all correct answers to a question are *helpful* answers to that question, and this is just one reason as to how that can happen.  The accepted answer is there for "was most helpful to the OP".  Your answer wasn't most helpful to the OP.  The OP is using the "accepted answer" feature correctly.

Comment: What can we do with users that don't understand that acceptance is optional? If your answer is any good it will get upvotes. In the long run those are worth much more than acceptance as you can get lots of them.

Comment: Maybe they unaccepted your answer because they think it *caused* the issue in their third question?

Comment: a better (but humorous) question would have been: "Why do users always accept the _worst_/less upvoted answer of all ?"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Accepting an answer is only statistically significant to the OP.  It means that this answer helped them out, and unlike any other type of content voting, **it can entirely be undone** at any time, for any reason.

A long time ago we had a [visible] metric called "acceptance rate", which was how often an OP accepted an answer.  This led to all sorts of nonsense, like people refusing to help if their accept rate was below a certain value, or discriminating against users if they didn't accept answers at all.

My advice to you is to simply let it go.  Accept votes are temporal and fleeting, but if two people upvote your answer, that already outweighs any accept reputation that you'd get.

Additionally, don't *just* appeal to the OP.  Doing so only ensures that this loop continues, since you'll be worried about if they'll accept your answer or not.  Appealing to a wider audience with a good and detailed answer is best.

Comment: Between your answer and [some related reading from the sidebar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256301/3775798), I think I'm starting to understand what you guys are saying here. Thank you for your insights.

Answer (score 7):

I think you have to change your attitude in the first place; you pushed me to accept your answer with your comment, which I didn't like; then you deleted that comment. Also, you stalked me for a couple of days and pointed me out to people without my knowledge.

When it comes to my third question, although the answer was not correct, it helped me (along with comments of others) to figure out what could be wrong with the current script. That's why I accepted.  I visited help center page for accepting answers; it seems like I haven't done anything that does not comply with the rules of the community. But in any case, I will be more careful next time when I ask questions and accept answers.

I didn't mean to offend you or create a noise for the community.  Sorry about this.

Comment: To clarify a couple things: my asking you to accept my answer was not meant as pushing, but as a reminder. New users forget all the time that they're supposed to accept helpful answers to their questions. I was under the impression that my answer helped you, so that's why I spoke up about it. I have also not been stalking you, but your questions kept coming up in the main feed around the same time each day that I've been on, and I noticed a pattern between them. That led to this Meta post.

Comment: As to my answer on the first question, if it was truly not helpful (as you, @Servy and the downvoters both there and here have all indicated), then I will delete it now because I am the one adding noise to the site then. At any rate, thank you for following up on Alon's comment to come here to express your views on the matter.

Comment: I didn't say it was not helpful, it answers to question that I asked, as you said, but does not solve my problem. I would have accepted if you didn't remind me to accept it. As I said earlier, I will be more careful with my questions next time