# Question with accepted answer not answering the question and no actual answer - what to do?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I have the exact same question as this OP:

[Is it possible to make git clone recursive by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23861208/is-it-possible-to-make-git-clone-recursive-by-default#23861991)

That question has an answer which might be useful, but it's not an answer to the question. Now, I happen to want an actual answer to the question (even if the answer is "it can't be done")... what should I do?

Comment: [This existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4261001/424903) seems to state that shadowing the command will do it.

Comment: [**accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you, personally**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/243725).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: I'm not the OP, I can't "accept" anything.

Comment: Op accepted an answer; you assert the answer is wrong. Op gets to determine what's correct - and as you objected - you are not op.

Comment: You keep searching or start your own question. Check out https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256311/2191572. You could also try commenting on the accepted answer and ask OP if they know whether or not a precise answer exists especially considering that they seem to be knowledgeable. Telling them that their answer is wrong and badgering with downvotes is not likely to end up in your favor.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: But that _is_ my own question, exactly and perfectly... also, the answer there is not wrong, it's a nice answer, it just doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: It's not _your own_ question: you aren't the OP. But I see what you mean. If you re-ask the question, then it's likely to get hammered to that one unless you clearly explain why the answer there isn't acceptable for you.

Comment: I must be missing something because I am not sure how Sahand is merely a typo of einpoklum. It might be the question in your mind but Sahand is the author of https://stackoverflow.com/q/23861208/2191572 so they get to decide what works/worked for them. Yes, you do not personally accept the accepted answer but, once again, you did not author the question.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: I did not author it, and yet, it is also my question. It's magic! Multiple people can have the same question.

Comment: The only magic is your stubbornness. Considering that you have more than 20k rep, I am surprised that you did not already know or do what I said in my first comment.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, *"start your own question"* - is bad suggestion if there is a duplicate. Though many doing it for various reasons, but don't be surprised to get downvotes even if you mention duplicate and explain the story. Bounty on existing question is *safest* recommendation and the [right action](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/219/investor) in such cases.

Comment: @Sinatr It depends. I tend to give a question a fair chance if their opening line is "I was able to find XYZ for my exact issue but unfortunately it only has one answer which does not precisely answer the question."

Comment: @ElliottFrisch "Op gets to determine what's correct" which is why we say that OP is the least qualified to assert which answer is "correct".

Comment: @MonkeyZeus ... which still doesn't justify an exact duplicate. Bounty up.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue mentioned in the meta post, the linked question is about to be closed as a dupe of a more general question [Is it possible to override git command by git alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3538774)

Comment: @Braiam Correct in the sense of being helpful to them personally. I can't tell you that you're wrong, when the question is who or what has helped you the most personally.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: So the answer could have been "Exercise more and eat less red meat"?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you feel that the existing answer doesn't answer the question, you can reflect that opinion with your vote.

If you want to provide information for the author on why their answer isn't useful, you're more than welcome to to post a comment explaining why it's not answering the question.

If you want to incentivise people to post an answer to the question that you feel would be useful, you can put a bounty on the question.

Comment: Just to add to the last point, when you post a bounty and select "Canonical answer required" as the reason, you're given a chance to enter a custom message where you can explain that the accepted answer doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score -4):

Why not just answer the question correctly?

You might find the accept is switched or that you get more votes than the accepted answer.

Comment: because he doesn't know the correct answer - he was asking how to get a correct answer.